# How to wrap text around button in Kivy?

Tags: python, button, text, kivy

I have three buttons (one column, three rows) in a GridLayout.
The text on the top of the button is centered but when it is too long it extends past the screen. How do I wrap it? Current code is:

```
self.add_widget(Button(text="", text_size = (None, self.height), halign = "center", valign = "center"))
```

for each of the buttons.

[image: Example]

Comment: You can try binding it's `text_size` to its `width`.

Comment: You mean `text_size = (self.width, self.height)`  ? It doesn't work, for some reason the whole text gets squeezed at the center (can't post a picture to show you).

Comment: With binding that should've worked. Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
text_size = (None, self.height)
```

as an arg to the `Button` constructor does not set up a binding. It just sets the `text_size` to the values at the moment that the `Button` `__init__()` method is executed. So the `text_size` gets set to `(None, 100)` and stays that way (the default `height` of a widget is `100`). If you want to actually have such a binding, you must either use the `Kivy` language, or set up the binding yourself. Something like this:

```
        butt = Button(text="", text_size = self.size, halign = "center", valign = "center")
        butt.bind(size=self.resize)
        self.add_widget(butt)

def resize(self, butt, new_size):
    butt.text_size = new_size
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have a question: what is being passed as the `new_size` argument in `butt.bind(size=self.resize)` in the `resize` function? (What's the argument syntax when using `bind`?
Also, if I wanted to use the Kivy language, would it be something like:
`<ClassName> \n GridLayout: \n Button: \n text_size : self.size ` ?

Comment: The arguments of a method (like `resize`) specified in a `bind` are the instance where the property ('size` in this case) has changed, and the new value of that property. And, yes, that `kv` looks right and will setup the binding automatically for you.

Comment: So how come `resize (self, butt, new_size)` takes three arguments, but `butt.bind(size=self.resize)` gives it none? (Or what is the argument syntax in that `.bind` expression?)

Comment: I described the arguments in my previous comments. I didn't mention the `self` argument as this is the first argument of any instance method. The `bind` command is only specifying the method to be called, not the arguments. The arguments are as described for any method bound to a property.

Comment: I am sorry if I fail to understand, but in `resize (self, butt, new_size)`, what is `butt` and what is `new_size` when calling it from `butt.bind(size=self.resize)` ?

Comment: It is not called from the `butt.bind()`, that only arranges for the `resize()` method to be called when the `size` property of that `Button` changes. When it is called, `butt` is the `Button` instance and `new_size` is the changed `size` of the `Button`.